# how to automatically delete the folders of more than one day in the crontab

Tags: cron, rm

I would like to delete all of the directories that are more than one day old, knowing that these directories can be empty or not. this command must be executed from the crontab every day.

I tried this command, but it doesn't work!

```
00 10 * * * find /applis/* -type d -mtime +1 -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Comment: Do you see your command listed on `grep -i cron /var/log/syslog`? DId you add that entry via `crontab -e`?